# Populate dropdown from data set in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to populate a dropdown in angular. I have a set of values that need to appear in the dropdown. Here is my code.

```
rolesArr: SelectItem[];

for (let i = 0; i < user.roles.length; i ++) {
    this.rolesArr = [
     { label: user.roles[i].name, value: i }
    ];
}

<div class="input-container">
     <label for="role">Role*</label>
     <p-dropdown [options]="rolesArr" formControlName="role" id="role" placeholder="Please select"></p-dropdown>
</div>
```

I am currently only seeing the last value in the data set.

This is my data set

```
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "System Admin",
      "parent": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Internal Account Manager",
      "parent": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "CAT Manager",
      "parent": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: share the 'p-dropdown' component aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning `rolesArr` every time when iterating `user.roles`.

1. Assign an array to `rolesArr`.
2. Call `rolesArr.push()` method.

```ts
rolesArr: SelectItem[] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < user.roles.length; i ++) {
    this.rolesArr.push({ label: user.roles[i].name, value: i });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what's expected with your current code. 
Be careful with your for loop. Every loop you re-assign the array to the current element.
What you should do instead is use `this.rolesArr.push({label:user.roles[i].name,value:i})`

Comment: I am now getting `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. I have added the data set in the question.

Comment: Add this line before the for loop " if(!this.rolesArr){ this.rolesArr = [] as SelectItem[] ;] "

Answer (score 1):

You are not pushing into the array. You are setting the 0 value of the array. Try it with.

```
for (let i = 0; i < user.roles.length; i ++) {
    this.rolesArr.push(
     { label: user.roles[i].name, value: i }
    );
}
```

Comment: I am now getting `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. I have added the data set in the question.